# Как добавить число к числу, которое имеется в таблице?

Tags: mysql, sql

Имеется число в таблице, нужно прибавить к числу в таблице, например 2.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
UPDATE `table_name` SET `field` = `field` + 2
```

и естественно условие WHERE

Comment: Спасибо, работает.

Comment: @MrTrojan, незачто

Answer (score 3):

```
UPDATE таблица SET столбец = `столбец` + 2 WHERE другой_стобец = строка
```

- это SQL

```
sql = "UPDATE таблица SET столбец = `столбец` + 2 WHERE другой_стобец"
```

- это php

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE таблица SET столбец = `столбец` + 2 WHERE другой_стобец")
```

- это wp